# Building a Floating Menu for SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery, client-object-model

I would like to have a floating menu the menu can come from a list or use the Quick launch.
Any ideas or samples out there..
For example if i can make this float
http://clarklab.net/blog/articles/dropdown/example.html
Cheers

Comment: ever get an answer? I am trying to do the same thing

Comment: @jasonus I went ahead and converted your answer to a comment. With a bit more  reputation, you will be able to [post comments everywhere](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few approaches to this. If you want to use the Quick Launch you'd probably need to manipulate the Quick Launch DOM with jQuery to create the desired effect. You can push your own styles, but the actual DOM structure around the Quick Launch isn't something that can easily be changed.

Your other option would be to use either the API or SPServices (http://spservices.codeplex.com) to query items from a list and render a nav as you described.

Both options would work and the majority of the work is simple CSS. There's probably a list query example on the SPServices site that you could use almost verbatim for your application if you wanted it list driven.

Just build a simple ul element with li's for each link and style them with CSS (add jQuery if you want sliding effects or other UX enhancements). Some of that could also be done with CSS3, but until more users adopt current browser versions that support CSS3 it's not a real viable option (unless this is an internal environment and you can guarantee browser version for all of your users).

Comment: thanks webdes03.
I have used SPServices and sure it a great idea just taught if there was a way to use the OTB quicklaunch